# Prove the sum of two closed space is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For $F$, $G$ closed subspaces of a Banach space $E$. Suppose $\exists C>0$ such that $$\forall x\in F+G,\exists(f,g)\in F\times G: x=f+g,||f||\le C||x|| ,||g||\le C||x||$$.

Prove that $F+G$ is closed.

I don't know how to use the condition. I guess we are supposed to construct a convergent sequence if $F$ or $G$ to approach a $x\in\overline{F+G}$. But I failed, could someone give me some help?

Thanks~

Comment: Can we assume that $F$ and $G$ have trivial intersection?

Comment: @Aweygan yes I think, but does it help?

Comment: Yes, because then the $\exists(f,g)$ becomes $\exists !(f,g)$

Comment: You are right. I feel it may help us in some way when constructing sequences. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: $F\times G$ is a Banach space. Show that $F\times G \to F+G$, $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$ is open and conclude that $F+G$ is complete (because quotients of Banach spaces are Banach).

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $F\cap G=\{0\}$, then we obtain uniqueness of the representation $x=f+g$, without which I could not find an argument showing this is true.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $F+G$ convergent to some $x\in E$.  By hypothesis, there exist sequences $\{f_n\}$ in $F$, $\{g_n\}$ in $G$ such that $\|f_n\|\leq C\|x_n\|$ and $\|g_n\|\leq C\|x_n\|$ for all $n$.  Then we have
$$\|f_n-f_m\|\leq C\|x_n-x_m\|,$$
$$\|g_n-g_m\|\leq C\|x_n-x_m\|,$$
and thus $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are Cauchy, hence convergent to some $f\in F$ and $g\in G$, respectively.  Since
$$\|x-(f+g)\|\leq\|x-x_n\|+\|f_n-f\|+\|g_n-g\|,$$
for all $n$, it follows that $x=f+g\in F+G$, and therefore $F+G$ is closed.

Comment: Why $\|f_n-f_m\|\leq C\|x_n-x_m\|$? Also you missed the equality $x_n=f_n+g_n$